# Where can I find the cpanfile format definition?

Tags: perl, perl-module

We consider to use *Minilla* or *Dist::Milla* for our perl development. Declaring dependencies is done via [cpanfile](http://search.cpan.org/~miyagawa/Module-CPANfile-0.9034/lib/cpanfile.pod). I expected to find an exact definintion of what and how can be declared. But

- perldoc cpanfile : 
  Shows only the principal usage. 'SEE ALSO' section does not help.
- perldoc Module::CPANfile: same as cpanfile.
- perldoc cpanfile-faq: no explanation of the exact syntax or a link to it, only

> Familiar DSL syntax
>
> This is a new file type, but the format and syntax isn't entirely new.
>   The metadata    it can declare is exactly a subset of "Prereqs" in
>   CPAN Meta Spec.
>
> The syntax borrows a lot from Module::Install. Module::Install is a
>   great way to easily declare module metadata such as name, author and
>   dependencies. cpanfile format is  simply to extract the dependencies
>   into a separate file, which means most of the     developers are
>   familiar with the syntax.

- Web : I found ( but does not answer my question )

  - https://speakerdeck.com/miyagawa/cpanfile
  - http://weblog.bulknews.net/post/44963580392/what-is-cpanfile-and-why-do-i-want-to-use-it
  - http://blogs.perl.org/users/lestrrat/2013/03/the-main-problem-with-cpan-modules-on-github.html

Does anybody know where to find an exact description of the [cpanfile](http://search.cpan.org/~miyagawa/Module-CPANfile-0.9034/lib/cpanfile.pod) syntax/format ?

Comment: Nowhere really. Go yell at miyagawa. :)

Comment: @hobbs: I do not want to yell. World is not perfect and so is Perl and its world. I just was surprised not to find documentation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I installed [`Module::CPANFile`](https://metacpan.org/module/cpanfile) and `perldoc cpanfile` and `perldoc cpanfile-faq`  were available.

The POD for `cpanfile` states:

```
[the] cpanfile specification (this document) is based on Ruby's
Gemfile http://gembundler.com/man/gemfile.5.html specification.
```

The link in the `cpanfile` manual page is broken. It should point to: http://bundler.io/v1.3/man/gemfile.5.html

`cpanfile` is designed to "backwards compatible" with [`Module::Install`](https://metacpan.org/module/Module%3a%3aInstall) DSL syntax and is "convertible to CPAN::Meta::Prereqs" and inspired by `CPAN::Meta Spec v.2` etc.

As I understand it `cpanfile` is somewhat of a "meta-format" and fits into a range of TIMTOWTDI approaches (see [miyagawa's blog describing `cpanfile`](http://weblog.bulknews.net/post/44963580392/what-is-cpanfile-and-why-do-i-want-to-use-it)), compatible with `Module::Install` and mostly self-documenting.  For example if you run `mymeta-cpanfile` inside a directory with `META` files it will build a `cpanfile` for you; you can write a script that describes prerequisites from `CPAN::Meta::Prereqs` and then `$file->save('cpanfile');` to write a `cpanfile`.

As for `Dist::Milla`, in the tutorial (see the [`POD`](https://metacpan.org/module/MIYAGAWA/Dist-Milla-v1.0.2/lib/Dist/Milla/Tutorial.pod) included with `Dist::Milla`) miyagawa points out that 
"If you decide to manually construct [a] new `cpanfile`, the format is mostly compatible to  `Module::Install`'s requirement DSL".  The tutorial also gives a short example.

I think it would be fair to ask [miyagawa](https://github.com/miyagawa/cpanfile) to clarify the status and use cases of the `cpanfile` specification/format *in the documentation for the distribution*. That and a few more examples would answer questions like yours. He has mostly done the work on this already - it is just not all in one place.

Comment: What does it mean 'based on' ? Same syntax, same semantics, extended perl features ... ? I'd like to read the exact format/definition FOR PERL or that I have to read the ruby gem spec ;-) ! Btw. the link is broken.

Comment: @katastrophos: But you did not write an issue for the broken link — well, I did it.

Comment: @SlavenRezic: you are right. Using that link you are redirected to http://bundler.io/man/gemfile.5.html which is a 'page not found' site. You have to go to the main page and start the search from there (which I did not).

Comment: @SlavenRezic and katastrophos - I fixed the link and added a a pull request upstream with the `cpanfile` github. Cheers

Comment: Thanks @G.Cito. It's interesting to see (like Module::Install's dependency hanling). Unfortunately it does not answer my question. I am curious about the outcome. Where do people know how to use cpanfile if there is no documentation ?

Comment: If you want a full on specification I believe you will still have to wait a while. It's been ~ 2 years+ but AFAIK @miyagawa still presents this as a "proposal".  A pretty specific proposal but not fully described in some sort of RFC.

Comment: @katastrophos - tried to make this into an "answer" to the extent possible. I doubt `cpanfile` will change in radically backwards incompatible ways but it may not be "complete" just yet. Now is your chance not only to use it but to help with the documentation/testing etc. :-)

Comment: @G.Cito: Thanks for your effort. I will accept your answer and I agree with your opinion. I already contacted Miyagawa and we will see. If we select Minilla/Dist::Zilla we surely will write documentation about cpanfile.