# Defining required packages and versions for a perl project

Tags: perl, cpan, package-managers

I am familiar with using `package.json` with node.js, `Gemfile` for Ruby, `Podfile` for Objective-C, et al.

What is the equivalent file for Perl and what is the syntax used?

I've installed a couple packages using cpanm and would like to save the package names and version in a single file that can be executed by team members.

Comment: [cpanfile](http://search.cpan.org/~miyagawa/Module-CPANfile-1.0002/lib/cpanfile.pod), http://stackoverflow.com/q/17696492/223226

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For simple use cases, writing a `cpanfile` is a good choice. A sample file might look like

```
requires 'Marpa::R2', '2.078';
requires 'String::Escape', '2010.002';
requires 'Moo', '1.003001';
requires 'Eval::Closure', '0.11';

on test => sub {
    requires 'Test::More', '0.98';
};
```

That is, it's actually a Perl script, not a data format. The dependencies can then be installed like

```
$ cd /path/to/your/module
$ cpanm --installdeps .
```

This does not install your module! But it makes sure that all dependencies are satisfied, so we can do:

```
use lib '/path/to/your-module/lib';  # add the location as a module search root
use Your::Module; # works! yay
```

This is usually sufficient e.g. for a git repository which you want others to tinker with.

---

If you want to create a tarball that can be distributed and installed easily, I'd recommend [`Dist::Zilla`](http://dzil.org/index.html) (although it's geared towards CPAN releases). Instead of a `cpanfile` we use a `dist.ini`:

```
name    = Your-Module
version = 1.2.3
author  = Your Self <you@example.com>
license = GPL_3
copyright_holder = Your Self

[@Basic]

[Prereqs]
Marpa::R2       = 2.078
String::Escape  = 2010.002
Moo             = 1.003001
Eval::Closure   = 0.11

[Prereqs / TestRequires]
Test::More      = 0.98
```

Then:

```
$ dzil test # sanity checks, and runs your tests
$ dzil build  # creates a tarball
```

Dist::Zilla takes care of creating a `Makefile.PL` and other infrastructure that is needed to install the module.

You can then distribute that tarball, and install it like `cpanm Your-Module-1.2.3.tar.gz`. Dependencies are resolved, your packages are copied to a permanent location, and you can now `use Your::Module` in any script without having to specify the location.

Note that you should adhere to the standard directory layout for Perl modules:

```
./
  lib/
    Your/
      Module.pm    # package Your::Module
      Module/
        Helper.pm  # package Your::Module::Helper
  t/  # tests to verify the module works on the target syste,
    foo.t
    bar.t
  xt/  # optional: Author tests that are not run on installation
    baz.t
  bin/ # optional: scripts that will later end up in the target system's $PATH
    command-line-tool
```

Comment: I usually use [`[AutoPrereqs]`](http://p3rl.org/Dist::Zilla::Plugin::AutoPrereqs) instead of [`[Prereqs]`](http://p3rl.org/Dist::Zilla::Plugin::Prereqs).

Answer (score -1):

`Makefile.PL` usually (along with a few other files; Perl has had packages for longer then any of the other languages you mention and suffers from a bit of inelegance here).

[Module Starter](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Module-Starter/) is a sensible way to start writing a package. It has a [getting started](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/XSAWYERX/Module-Starter-1.62/getting-started.html) guide.